# Gain error calculation for op-amp circuit in inverting configuration

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback, frequency-response, cutoff-frequency, loop-gain

For an inverting op-amp, calculate minimum gain that is required for the op-amp to achieve a gain error of 1%, if the required closed-loop DC gain is -9.

If the input resistance R1 is 1Kohm,find the feedback resistance R2 that achieves the required gain of closed loop.

Calculate the settling time, if the amplifier is applied a small step input and the response reaches 94% of it's final steady-state value. The op-amp, in open-loop condition, assumed to have only a single dominant pole at ω−3dB=6M Rad/Sec.

[image: here is the complete picture]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Add the steps that you have already followed to reach the answer by using the [edit] button below your question. It will improve the chances of getting an answer.

Comment: What is the open loop gain of the opamp ? Is that value not reqired along with \$\omega_{3dB}\$ to get an answer ? Also, what do you mean by *gain error* ?

Comment: The gain error is given to find the open loop gain i thought.

Comment: Would you consider that part of the question (open loop gain calculation) already answered then ?